# How do I place more than one iteration of an image onto another single image in a recursive way in Racket?

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to create a function which places n white clouds onto a blue sky at random places. I've tried using place-image, but I can't figure out how to get more than one dot on it. I looked at place-images, place-image/align, but I understand place-image is the easiest. The function needs to take number of dots, a width of the black sky, and the height.

Comment: Deleting answered questions isn't the Stack Overflow way—we want answers to be able to help others with the same problem! So I'm going to revert your most recent edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I believe you've already got the answer you need—you've already got a way to add one dot. That means you have a way to take a black sky—an image—and add a white dot to create a new image. Now, all you need to do is to take *that* image, and add another white dot to it (using the same approach as you did to add your first white dot), and so on and so forth.

That is what is meant by "recursive way" (as mentioned in your question title).

---

Your code (thanks for posting it!) lacks a base case for the recursion. That is why it never exits.

Here's a fixed (I hope) version of the code (not tested, but hopefully gets the right idea across):

```
(define (draw-cloudy-sky num-clouds width height)
  (cond ((zero? num-clouds) (rectangle width height "solid" "skyblue"))
        (else (place-image (circle 10 "solid" "grey") (random width) (random height)
              (draw-cloudy-sky (sub1 num-clouds) width height))))
```

Comment: @KrissyMichaelsson Can you edit the question to include the code you wrote, that caused the infinite loops?

Comment: @KrissyMichaelsson I edited my answer with a (hopefully) fixed version. Good luck!